Reverse scroll/swipe direction "Switch desktops" on Windows 11 using touchpad
I'm aware of changing the scroll direction for scrolling on pages and textarea and what not. But the same thing can not be done for switching desktops as far as I could find.
I've currently enabled the 4 finger gestures (left and right) for switching desktops as can be seen here. How can I change the direction? I'd like to "switch" left with right.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
